# Cross-Origin Read Blocking response from local server

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, localhost, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have this code:

```
function send_sound_file(file) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const messageElement = document.createElement('div');

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }

     try {
         xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8091/sound/")
     }
     catch (e) {
         alert(e.message);
        return;
     }

      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

      xhr.send(file);
}
```

This code sends the recorded audio file to the local server for verification. 
The server should return JSON.But I get the following error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
>   http://localhost:8091/sound/ with MIME type application/json.

I do not have access to the source files of my local server.
And my js code will only run from the file system, for example: file:///C:/Users/Desktop/web/index1.html.

How can I solve my problem of getting a JSON from the local server?

Comment: Probably the response with MIME type application/json isn't actually JSON. Look in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to find out what it is.

Comment: In Google Chrome in "Response" I see: "This request has no response data available".
In Firefox I see: 
Content-Length: 530
Content-Type:  application/json
Server: Mongoose/6.12e

And "Response": { "code": 114, "version": { "library": "1.0.8.0", "configuration": "v1", "service": "1.0.8.9" }, "metadata": { "length": { "value": 1464.000, "state": "passed" }... and so on

But I can use only Chrome

Comment: Sounds like something about the request in chrome is causing a problem in your server side code and it isn't returning anything there.

Comment: I can see in the server console that it returns the data correctly

Comment: The 73 chrome update has some new restrictions. You can check the description here: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers However, I haven't found the answer to this.